# spring data jpa - class based projections with custom query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to have a spring data repository method for a custom query and would like to use class based projection.

Looking at this 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int age;
}

@Value // lombok annotation to create constructor, equals and hash-code
public class PersonDTO {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

List<PersonProjection> findDistinct();

@Query("select distinct firstName, lastName from Person")
List<PersonProjection> findDistinctQuery();

@Query(value = "select distinct first_name, last_name from person", nativeQuery = true)
List<PersonProjection> findDistinctNativeQuery();

}
```

- findDistinct works well
- findDistinctQuery and findDistinctNativeQuery throw

> No converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
>   to type [com.x.PersonDTO]

Is there any option to make it work with classes (not interfaces)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please write your method in person repository like below

```
@Query(value = "select distinct new xxx.xxx.dto.PersonDTO(p.first_name, p.last_name) from person p")
List<PersonProjection> findDistinctNativeQuery();
```

"xxx.xxx.dto.PersonDTO" this should point to your fully qualified class name.

for your reference please look into this
https://www.bytestree.com/spring/spring-data-jpa-projections-5-ways-return-custom-object/

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't even use native query.

Comment: Thanks Mate for the reference link.

Comment: This doesn't work with native queries.

Comment: Yeah true @birca

Answer (score 6):

This works too:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT DISTINCT fist_name AS firstName, last_name AS lastName FROM person ")
    List<PersonNameOnly> findDistinctNames();

    interface PersonNameOnly {
        String getFirstName;
        String getLastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure there is a Spring Data solution for native query, but you can use JPA [ConstructorResult](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#ConstructorResult_.28JPA_2.1.29):

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name="Person.findDistinctNativeQuery",
        query="select distinct first_name as firstName, last_name as lastName from person",
        resultSetMapping="PersonMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="PersonMapping",
        classes={
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass=PersonDTO.class, columns={
                        @ColumnResult(name="firstName", type=String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="lastName", type=String.class)
                })
        })
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}

@Value // lombok annotation to create constructor, equals and hash-code
public class PersonDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

    List<PersonProjection> findDistinct();

    @Query("select distinct firstName, lastName from Person")
    List<PersonProjection> findDistinctQuery();

    @Query(name = "Person.findDistinctNativeQuery", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonDTO> findDistinctNativeQuery();

}
```

Or you can return Object[] from findDistinctNativeQuery() and then manually create PersonDTO.

With HQL you can use class based projections as well, the only condition PersonDTO must have the all argument constructor which parameter names must match properties of the root entity class:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

    ...

    List<PersonDTO> findDistinct();

}
```

If PersonDTO properties doesn't match the base entity properties, than [HQL dynamic instantiation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause) may be used. Again, this doesn't work with native query:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

    ...

    @Query("select new com.x.PersonDTO(firstName, lastName) from Person")
    List<PersonDTO> findDistinct();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
default List<PersonDTO> findDistinctQuery() {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Person p) -> {
        SELECT(DISTINCT(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()));
        FROM(p);
    });
    return query.createQuery(getEntityManager(), PersonDTO.class).getResultList();
}
```

**Note**, that you must annotate PersonDTO with `@Data` and not `@Value`. More details about [JPA Repositories integration](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Repositories).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constructor with fields name same as root entity. So your DTO would be,

```
public class PersonDTO {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  // constructor , getters setters, equals(…) and hashCode() implementations 
}
```

You can simplify DTO by using Lombok’s `@Value` annotation,

```
 @Value
 class PersonDTO {
    String firstname, lastname;
 }
```

Check more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos)

Comment: @Code_Mode, this is required for findDistinct to work. But custom queries still don't work.

Comment: Because this doesn't answer the question. But OK, I removed down-vote.

Comment: Updated the description to make it more clear that DTO satisfies all requirements for class-based projection.

Comment: @Code_Mode, I already removed my down-vote, please also do the same.

Comment: @Boris not mine

Comment: You can try with alias, select distinct p.firstName, p.lastName from Person p. Also you could use contructor, select com.pkg.PersonDTO(p.firstName, p.lastName) rom Person p. Hope it helps.